# How could I use scipy library to get the distance?

Tags: python

I just started to learn python, and my teacher asks me to simulate the model rocket trajectory knowing the thrust of the engine.

I have already got the speed and the acceleration of the rocket using odeint function. However, I don't know how to use the speed and time.

I've already got to get the distance the rocket traveled since the speed is solved by odeint function.

here's the code I wrote to get the speed:

```
def getforce(t):
    if 0<=t<0.15:
        F = 40*t
    elif 0.15<=t<0.7:
        F = -9.09*t+7.36
    elif 0.7<=t<1.25:
        F = 1
    elif 1.25<=t<1.65:
        F = 7.5*t-8.375
    elif 1.65<=t<1.8:        
        F = -26.6*t+48
    else:
        F = 0
    return F

def getspeed(x,t):
    Ft = getforce(t)
    y0,y1 = x
    dy0 = y1
    dy1 = (Ft-0.0001277422*y1**2*np.sign(y1)-0.174)/0.0177
    return dy0,dy1

t = np.linspace(0,10,100)
sol = si.odeint(getspeed,(0,0),t)
plt.plot(t,sol[:,0])
plt.show()
```

Comment: You could just integrate the distance from the speed.  v(t)= dx/dt.  To numerically integrate the first naive (and good enough for this relatively smooth problem) approach is to start at zero, then add v*deltat at each step.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I knew that I should integrate the distance from the speed, but I don't know how I'm supposed to use the speed(which is a numpy array) to put in another function. Could you elaborate or write down the code if possible?

Comment: There's no need, I think I've already got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that everything else is correct, you just integrate the speed by hand.

(The reason I can't check on the overall correctness easily is that you are using an unorthodox (given) expression in the speed section, rather than solving the rocked equation that includes the mass loss F= m a --> d(m*v)/dt = dm/dt * v + m * dv/dt.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as si
%matplotlib inline

def getforce(t):
    if 0<=t<0.15:
        F = 40*t
    elif 0.15<=t<0.7:
        F = -9.09*t+7.36
    elif 0.7<=t<1.25:
        F = 1
    elif 1.25<=t<1.65:
        F = 7.5*t-8.375
    elif 1.65<=t<1.8:        
        F = -26.6*t+48
    else:
        F = 0
    return F

def getspeed(x,t):
    Ft = getforce(t)
    y0,y1 = x
    dy0 = y1
    dy1 = (Ft-0.0001277422*y1**2*np.sign(y1)-0.174)/0.0177
    return dy0,dy1

t = np.linspace(0,10,100)
sol = si.odeint(getspeed,(0,0),t)
v=sol[:,0]

x=0
xs=[]
dt=t[1]-t[0] # use linspace with 101 to get the sample distance you'd normally expect
for i in range(len(v)):
    x=x+v[i]*dt
    xs.append(x)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(t,v)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(t,xs)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I didn't use numpy or lambda expressions to integrate to keep it easily readable and because the speed of execution is immaterial for this case.

Comment: Oh thank you so much!! I thought I would have to use the scipy function again to get the distance, but I think actually this approach is more easy to understand. Thanks again!

Comment: Even if you use higher level functions from scipy or numpy, in numerical computing one should always compare with some other number that you can easily calculate, be that a special case in a back-of-the-envelope calculation or your own code.